# Finding a monochromatic cycle in clique

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

1) what is the minimum $n$ such that in every $2$ - coloring of $K_n$ there exist a monochromatic copy of $C_m$ ?

2) moreover, what is the minimum $n$ such that in every $r$ - coloring of $K_n$ there exist a monochromatic cycle?

I found that the answer to 1 is known, but I don't find it.
http://www.mate.unlp.edu.ar/~liliana/lawclique_2016/21.pdf - (page 24)

Comment: For (1) see [R. J. Faudree and R. H. Schelp, All Ramsey numbers for cycles in graphs, *Discrete Math.* 8 (1974), 313–329](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X74901514) and earlier work referenced therein.

Comment: The answer to (2) is $2r+1$ since the [arboricity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arboricity.html) of the complete graph $K_n$ is $\lceil n/2\rceil.$

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate on a comment of bof.  For positive integers $r$ and $s$, let $c(r,s)$ denote the smallest positive integer $n$ such that if we color the edges of a clique on $n$ vertices with red and blue, either the red subgraph contains a cycle of length $r$ or the blue subgraph contains a cycle of length $s$.  The main theorem of Faudree and Schelp [[All Ramsey numbers for cycles in graphs, *Discrete Math*. 8 (1974), 313-329](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X74901514)] is the following.

(i) If $3\le s\le r$ and $s$ is odd and $(r,s)\ne (3,3)$, then $c(r,s)=2r-1$.
(ii) If $4\le s\le r$ and $s$ and $r$ are even and $(r,s)\ne (4,4)$, then $c(r,s)=r+\frac12s+1$.
(iii) If $4\le s < r$ and $s$ is even and $r$ is odd, then $c(r,s)=\max(r+\frac12s-1,2s-1)$.

So the answer to (1), to guarantee a monochromatic copy of $C_m$, comes by setting $r=s=m$.  To complete the answer, we mention that $c(3,3)=c(4,4)=6$.